# Solve PDE Numerically for only the inhomogeneous part

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I want to solve

```
NDSolve[{D[H[r], r, r] + D[H[r], r]/r + k^2 H[r] == DiracDelta[r]/r}, H[r], r]
```

For only the inhomogeneous part. How would put this idea in terms of boundary conditions?

Answer (score 3):

It seems Mathematica is able to solve this directly via `DSolve`.

```
FullSolution = 
 H[r] /. First[
   DSolve[{D[H[r], r, r] + D[H[r], r]/r + k^2 H[r] == 
      DiracDelta[r]/r}, H[r], r]];
HomeogenouseSolution = 
 H[r] /. First[
   DSolve[{D[H[r], r, r] + D[H[r], r]/r + k^2 H[r] == 0}, H[r], r]];
ParticularSolution = Simplify[FullSolution - HomeogenouseSolution]
```

Shows

```
(1/2)*(Pi*BesselY[0, k*r]*HeavisideTheta[r] + 
   2*BesselJ[0, k*r]*
    Integrate[(-(1/2))*Pi*BesselY[0, k*K[1]]*DiracDelta[K[1]], 
          {K[1], 1, r}])
```

Comment: I'm aware, but I indent to make this problem more complicated

Comment: @grdgfgr Is there a reason that you wish to make this problem "complicated" as you say?  In that case, boundary conditions would be useful for this problem.  Could you please specify them?

Comment: Instead of DiracDelta[r]/r on the RHS, I might have an arbitrary function of k multiplied by DiracDelta[r]/r, or something else altogether. I am interested in solving for only the inhomogeneous part. If DSolve gives me a closed form solution with two arbitrary constants, I can just equate them to zero but I do not know how to make NDSolve understand my intentions.

Comment: @grdgfgr Then I think the easiest (if not the best) solution is to use something like `With[{a = 100}, a/Pi Exp[-a r^2]]` instead of `DiracDelta[r]`. As far as I can tell, `DiracDelta` is just a ideal model of point source, we use it because it makes symbolic analysis easier, for numeric calculation it's no more than a trouble maker, why not abandon it?